# Applescript: (Can’t make paragraph 2 of […] into type Unicode text.)

Tags: applescript

```applescript
tell application "Mail"
        set emailSelection to (get selection)
    set theText to content of (item 1 of the emailSelection)
    set subText to paragraph 1 of theText
end tell
```

I get an error saying:

> (*Can’t make paragraph 2 of "Below is the result of your feedback form.  It was submitted by" into type Unicode text.*)

Note the para 1 para 2 difference also.

---

EDIT

Also just tried copying contents of message content into a new object (unreferenced) to remove any object  specific weirdness. But the error message still refers back to the Mail message not the new object which I would think is wrong.

```applescript
try
tell application "Mail"

    set emailSelection to (get selection)
    set theMessage to (item 1 of the emailSelection)
    log "1 ****** " & return & content of theMessage

    copy contents of (item 1 of the emailSelection) to theText
    log " 2 ****** " & return & content of theText

    set subText to (the first paragraph of theText)
    log " 3 ****** " & return & content of theText

    --  set subText to paragraph 1 of theText as Unicode text

end tell

on error the error_message number the error_number
    display dialog "Error: " & the error_number & ". " & the error_message buttons {"OK"} default button 1
end try
```

Error msg:

> Error: -1728. Mail got an error: Can’t get paragraph 1 of message id 740166 of mailbox "INBOX" of account "IMAP PL…".

Comment: I also tried appending "as string" to 4th line: same error

Comment: Does this work on any other emails apart from this one. Also is this feed back form something we can access to get an email from it to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script seems to work on my machine (OS X 10.9.1).

May be that helps to diagnose (try-block spits out an error message when something fails):

```
tell application "Mail"
    try
        set emailSelection to (get selection)
        set theText to content of (item 1 of the emailSelection)
        set subText to paragraph 1 of theText
    on error the error_message number the error_number
        display dialog "Error: " & the error_number & ". " & the error_message buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    end try

end tell
```

I tested it with a newly created message and also with some received messages. May be it's the format of the message that isn't working here. Because of that thought it may help to do something like this?

```
set subText to (paragraph 1 of theText) as Unicode text
```

Comment: Hi DigiMonk I tried "as string" and "as Unicode text" but same error. perplexing.

Comment: Ok. And does the script also not work with a newly created (& saved and selected) message?

Comment: It works today without the "as Unicode". Maybe I just needed to reboot my system?

Comment: … when it comes to very unexpected and sometimes strange problems with the scripting system a reboot is probably the recommended way to go => if it still fails after a reboot it's time to dig deeper.